# Laravel schedule:work command displays errors though there are no errors

Tags: laravel, cron

I have setup two cron jobs on my local Laravel 9 project setup. Both these jobs check if the job has not been run for today in a cronjob table. If the job has not run, it runs the job and creates a record in the cronjob table. If the job has already run, it returns 1. Currently, I am running both jobs every minute.

I use `php artisan schedule:work`  to run cron and it runs the two jobs which I can verify by looking at the cronjob table. When it goes to run the two jobs again, the terminal displays the FAIL error messages as shown below, though I don't see any error message in the storage/logs/laravel.log file.

```
    Home@MacBook-Air cota % php artisan schedule:work 

   INFO  Running schedule tasks every minute.  

  2023-03-10 18:16:00 Running ['artisan' overDueTasksNotification]  2,152ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.4/bin/php' 'artisan' overDueTasksNotification > '/dev/null' 2>&1  
  2023-03-10 18:16:02 Running ['artisan' tasksDueToday] ......... 1,357ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.4/bin/php' 'artisan' tasksDueToday > '/dev/null' 2>&1  

  2023-03-10 18:17:00 Running ['artisan' overDueTasksNotification]  876ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.4/bin/php' 'artisan' overDueTasksNotification > '/dev/null' 2>&1  
  2023-03-10 18:17:01 Running ['artisan' tasksDueToday] ......... 1,175ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.4/bin/php' 'artisan' tasksDueToday > '/dev/null' 2>&1  

  2023-03-10 18:18:00 Running ['artisan' overDueTasksNotification]  1,156ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.4/bin/php' 'artisan' overDueTasksNotification > '/dev/null' 2>&1  
  2023-03-10 18:18:01 Running ['artisan' tasksDueToday] ........... 903ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.4/bin/php' 'artisan' tasksDueToday > '/dev/null' 2>&1  

^C
Home@MacBook-Air cota % tail -n 50 storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Though everything seems to be working fine, I am curious about these error messages.
Any idea?

Comment: You don't see any error message, because you redirect output `/dev/null` in a weird way. Why not remove that piece orrrr, manually run that artisan command, see what your log will show and of course, update your original question

Comment: I have manually used  the “php artisan schedule:work” command, and everything else is being generated by Laravel. And I don’t any output in the log file; all the output is being generated on the terminal.

Comment: > `all the output is being generated on the terminal`
yes, perfect, copy / paste the output from the terminal, there should be errors in there. that's why your `schedule:run` is failing